# URL redirection based on environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis

I hosted my application in three different environments listed like dev.www.abc.com, test.www.abc.com, www.abc.com(prod) here i need redirect my sites as listed below

```
dev.www.abc.com --> www.somewebsite1.com
test.www.abc.com --> www.somewebsite2.com
www.abc.com --> www.somewebsite3.com
```

How can we create URL redirection rule based on the website name?

Comment: create a key in web.config file and you can use it in controller for redirection method or you can create constant also

Comment: you could create a separate rule at application level or you can create a rule like [img](https://i.imgur.com/ZDvuiQO.png) at server level to redirect particular application.